# Parsing java InputStream which has several protobuf inside

Tags: java, parsing, inputstream, protocol-buffers, netty

Format of incoming message

- 1st byte is fixed
- protobuf message in role of header (9 bytes)
- protobuf message in role of contents (4 bytes)

I implement two protobuf messages in one network packet for flexibility.

This is how I am trying to parse the message:

```
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf.array());
System.out.println(is.available());
is.skip(1);
System.out.println(is.available());

MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.parseFrom(is);
System.out.println(is.available());
```

Output is

- 14
- 13
- 0

So the problem is that parseFrom tries to read the inputStream until the end and does not stop once first protobuf reading is done.

What would be the best way to parse the message having this kind of format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I write to and parse from now I use `writeDelimitedTo` and `parseDelimitedFrom` and it works.